# Laravel unauthorized routes showing 404 on shared hosting server

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, routes

For some reason my unauthorized route shows a 404 for my Laravel project:

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('bookings', 'BookingController');
    Route::get('bookings.export', 'BookingController@export')->name('bookings.export');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
         return redirect('/dashboard');
});

Route::get('/bookings/contract', 'BookingController@contract')->name('contract');
```

When I try to access `/bookings/contract` I get a 404 error. It's strange because if I try to access `bookings.export` it works fine.

I am on a shared hosting so I don't have access to a vhost, I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.php3 index.phtml index.php5 index.shtml mwindex.phtml

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    #    Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi You're wrong, Laravel named routes are used if you want to access them programmatically for redirects etc... It's the path that you need to access for a normal url request.

Comment: place the `contract` route before the `Route::group`

Comment: @NorrisOduro Wow that seemed to have done it, why is that though? If you write this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: Is your `show` method works for you ? Inside `BookingController` by calling `bookings/{booking_id}` route .is.  `booking/1` with get verbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `Route::group` which has a `Resource` route for `booking` in it, laravel tries to find all `booking` routes in that group.

To use another route which has the `booking` prefix, place it above the `Route::group`